# Can I add submenu to dropdownlist having listitem

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to use a submenu to dropdown list by using list or option but it doesn't allow to use list or option. Can any one help? I want to add submenu in support option.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPhase" CssClass="selectbox1" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Value="-1">-SELECT-</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Analysis" Value="Analysis"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Planning" Value="Planning"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Execution" Value="Execution"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Control" Value="Control"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Support" Value="Support"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: Hi vicky can you let us know if my answer helped you out and mark as answered to benefit other people who come and might have the same question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not believe that this can be done with the standard `ASP DropDownList` control.

Have you looked at using the `ASP Menu` control instead:

```
<asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server">
    <Items>
        <asp:MenuItem Value="-1" Text="-SELECT-">
            <asp:MenuItem Text="Analysis" Value="Analysis"></asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem Text="Planning" Value="Planning"></asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem Text="Execution" Value="Execution"></asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem Text="Control" Value="Control"></asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem Text="Support" Value="Support">
                <asp:MenuItem Text="Sub Menu Item 1" Value="SM1"></asp:MenuItem>
                <asp:MenuItem Text="Sub Menu Item 2" Value="SM2"></asp:MenuItem>
            </asp:MenuItem>
        </asp:MenuItem>
    </Items>
</asp:Menu>
```

Comment: yes it does but we can't add text between menu Item closing and starting tag

Comment: Do you mean the first menu-item `-SELECT-` ? I'm not entirely clear on what you mean here.

Comment: @vicky Please see updated answer and let me know if that works. I have corrected it once more.

Comment: @vicky Great - please remember to mark my answer as answered so it will help others who come across the same question as you. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow